# XSLT with nested for-each-group to display unique combination of sibling elements

Tags: xml, xslt

### Heading ##Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report_Data>
    <Report_Entry>
    
        <cost_center>
            <ID>CC</ID>
        </cost_center>
        
        <cost_center_site>
            <ID>CCS1</ID>
        </cost_center_site>
        
        <cost_center_site>
            <ID>CCS2</ID>
        </cost_center_site>
        
        <cost_center_site>
            <ID>CCS3</ID>
        </cost_center_site>
        
        <gl_company>
            <ID>G1</ID>
        </gl_company>
        
        <gl_company>
            <ID>G2</ID>
        </gl_company>
        
    </Report_Entry>
</Report_Data>
```

Applied XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:output method = "text"/>
    <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xA;'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="delim" select="','"/>
    
    
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Report_Entry" />
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Report_Entry">
        <xsl:text>cost_center,cost_center_site,gl_company</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
        
        <xsl:for-each-group select="cost_center" group-by="ID">
            
            <xsl:for-each-group select="../cost_center_site" group-by="ID">
   
                <xsl:for-each-group select="../gl_company" group-by="ID">
                    
                    <xsl:value-of select="../cost_center/ID"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$delim"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="../cost_center_site/ID"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$delim"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>                    
                
                </xsl:for-each-group>
                
            </xsl:for-each-group>
            
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        


    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Getting Following Results:

| cost_center | cost_center_site | gl_company |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CC | CCS1 CCS2 CCS3 | G1 |
| CC | CCS1 CCS2 CCS3 | G2 |
| CC | CCS1 CCS2 CCS3 | G1 |
| CC | CCS1 CCS2 CCS3 | G2 |
| CC | CCS1 CCS2 CCS3 | G1 |
| CC | CCS1 CCS2 CCS3 | G2 |

Expected Results:

| cost_center | cost_center_site | gl_company |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CC | CCS1 | G1 |
| CC | CCS1 | G2 |
| CC | CCS2 | G1 |
| CC | CCS2 | G2 |
| CC | CCS3 | G1 |
| CC | CCS3 | G2 |

I tried using current-grouping-key() and for-each in inner loop to display unique cost center site value on each row but couldn't get the cost center to repeat on each row. Would appreciate if someone can assist in providing inputs to the xslt in order to get achieve the expected results.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be more like

```
<xsl:template match="Report_Entry">
    <xsl:text>cost_center,cost_center_site,gl_company</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="." group-by="cost_center/ID">
        <xsl:variable name="cc-id" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="cost_center_site/ID">
            <xsl:variable name="ccs-id" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="gl_company/ID">
                <xsl:value-of select="$cc-id, $ccs-id, current-grouping-key()" separator="{$delim}"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>                    
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```